# Customize or create Starling animations, movements and Transitions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, flash-builder, starling-framework

Since I don't know english very well, I'm not able to find clear examples and/or tutorials for what I'm trying to do.
So the (maybe stupid) question is:
How can I strongly customize tweens using Starling framework and make my Sprites(or MovieClips) following a line, curve or create every other non-linear movement that doesn't exist in Transition Class?
I have no problem with Basic Starling animation. So it should be a good start point. 
Thanks in advance for examples, resources or suggestions.

PS. I already visit the "Starling Wiki" page about custom Transitions but, as a Beginner(almost Intermediate) coder I wasn't able to completely understand it.
I know there are many online resources about AS3/Starling/Flash/Nape/Box2D but it's not easy for a non-english Beginner programmer to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple move Starling's movieClip by set .x .y .rotation

Comment: Your solution seems to do what I need, but when I try to change pivotX an pivotY points to make my image rotate around them, Flash Builder throws me an error (I changed pivotPoints working on Sprite,MovieClip and Image but I got the same error: "inaccessible method pivotX through a reference with static type starling.display:Image", maybe the Embedded Image is the problem?)

Comment: try to convert you symbol to starling's movieclip

Comment: I tried. Error in converting Texture to Vector that is required by starling's MovieClips:
'myMc=new MovieClip(Assets.getTexture('texture'));'

Comment: Ok. I'm actually stupid. I was setting "pivot points" writing **pivotX(value)** instead of **pivotX=value**. So I didn't need to convert images to DisplayObjects. Thank you for the best (and maybe easiest) way for customize movements when tweening.

Answer (score 0):

Since now, I haven't heard of scripted transition to make predefined non linear movement. As you said, you can move object from one position to another, but it won't happen in a curved line.

What I've done in the past is to predefine the path of the movement, as I needed exactly the same weird path. I did a path tween in Flash, then used one simple function to loop through all frames (using `gotoAndStop()`) and getting `x` and `y` property of the object, storing them in an array. This was done when initializing. Later on I could start animation on all my weird paths whenever I wanted, using `onUpdate` method of tween, and passing positions from the array I've populated in the beginning.

This of course is good if you have very weird paths. If you want very little curves, you could try to do a mathematical equation. Tween classes have an `update` function, which will be called on each frame. So on each frame you could do some calculations and modify the parameters. For example if you tween `x` and `y` properties, you could use the `update` function to add a random number to those values. Of course this will make very uncontrolled movement, I'm just giving an example.

**The best solution** I could think of, speaking of **complexity/result ratio** - to use Greensock's [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/bezier-speed-test/) (look at the second example) - it has a built in bezier tweening. This means it could move from point A to point B within a bezier curve. I think this will be a good solution for your problem :)

Comment: Thank you Andrey. onUpdate function was one of the first things I tryied to do. The problem is that Flash Builder doesn't recognize it (I don't know why, it throws me an error). I also tryied whit ENTER_FRAME and nothing happens.